# Can not login Jira with Api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I have this code below, i need to login but Jira documantation so bad that i cant figured out, how can i login to jira ? They say basic auth is depreced but all examples are like this. How can i login ?

var apiUrl = @"https://MYDOMAIN.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/MYPROJECTNAME";

```
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), apiUrl))
                {
                   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xxxxx@gmail.com:1xxxxxk2qdnqHJxxxx155"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Osman. Basic auth with email addresses + password to Jira CLOUD has been deprecated for many years. If you want to use basic auth, you must use keys + tokens (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/). You are probably reading old documentation, or the wrong documentation for Jira SERVER with the v2 REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, documentation too weak.

In my use cases, I preferred using "username" only. Not email. Can you try this?

```
var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<YOUR_USERNAME>:1xzyNAGgksdfgP3155"));
```

This is Jira [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/):

> The username and password of a user who has permission to create issues on your Jira Server site
>
> Build a string of the form username:password.

If this recommendation fails can you share your rest logs?

Comment: Here is response: {"errorMessages":["Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it."],"errors":{}}
But i can create issue from web page

Comment: Clearly you are authenticated successfully, You may check permissions and query params. Also common mistake is trying request an issue from wrong jira software (Service Management Software, Jira Software). That's only explanation for creating successfull but requesting unsuccessfull.

Comment: when i paste the requested url to browser, i can get the issue so my permissions are given i think, but trying from code respond me this message. i think i can not login from code.

Comment: i updated the code on question

Comment: Mehmed. You have provided a link to Jira SERVER documentation, and the OP has a problem with authentication to Jira CLOUD. The two have totally different REST APIs.